# Postgres sub query returns 1 row, but exists returns false

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, subquery, exists

I'm not sure how this is possible. This is an inner query for a NOT EXISTS test.

```
 SELECT subq.* FROM(
        SELECT distinct on("contractId") "contractId", clients.id, clients.name, "contractHistory".status, "contractHistory"."timeStamp", first_value("contractHistory"."id") over(partition by "contractId" order by "timeStamp" desc) as window
          FROM "contractHistory", "clients", "contracts"
          WHERE "contractHistory"."contractId" = "contracts"."id"
          AND "clients"."id" = "contracts"."clientId"
          AND contracts.opened < now()
          AND contracts.expires > now() + '1 day'::interval
        ) AS subq
      WHERE subq.status = 'Signed'
      AND subq.id = 12345
  ;
```

> (1 row)

If I change the outer SELECT to count(subq.*) I get:

> ### count
>
> ```
>  1
> ```

So far so good. But wrap the entire original query in SELECT EXISTS and:

> ### exists
>
> f

Why is this? I need this query to be wrapped in an outer query:

```
SELECT * FROM "clients" AS c WHERE status = 'Active' AND NOT EXISTS(
SELECT subq.* FROM(
            SELECT distinct on("contractId") "contractId", clients.id, clients.name, "contractHistory".status, "contractHistory"."timeStamp", first_value("contractHistory"."id") over(partition by "contractId" order by "timeStamp" desc) as window
              FROM "contractHistory", "clients", "contracts"
              WHERE "contractHistory"."contractId" = "contracts"."id"
              AND "clients"."id" = "contracts"."clientId"
              AND contracts.opened < now()
              AND contracts.expires > now() + '1 day'::interval
            ) AS subq
          WHERE subq.status = 'Signed'
          AND subq.id = c.id
);
```

It is returning a row for the outer query even though the inner query returns 1 row.

Edit to add SELECT EXISTS:

```
 SELECT EXISTS(
      SELECT subq.* FROM(
        SELECT distinct on("contractId") "contractId", clients.id, clients.name, "contractHistory".status, "contractHistory"."timeStamp", first_value("contractHistory"."id") over(partition by "contractId" order by "timeStamp" desc) as window
          FROM "contractHistory", "clients", "contracts"
          WHERE "contractHistory"."contractId" = "contracts"."id"
          AND "clients"."id" = "contracts"."clientId"
          AND contracts.opened < now()
          AND contracts.expires > now() + '1 day'::interval
        ) AS subq
      WHERE subq.status = 'Signed'
      AND subq.id = 12345
  );
```

> ### exists
>
> f
>   (1 row)

And just for completeness:

```
SELECT 1 FROM(
        SELECT distinct on("contractId") "contractId", clients.id, clients.name, "contractHistory".status, "contractHistory"."timeStamp", first_value("contractHistory"."id") over(partition by "contractId" order by "timeStamp" desc) as window
          FROM "contractHistory", "clients", "contracts"
          WHERE "contractHistory"."contractId" = "contracts"."id"
          AND "clients"."id" = "contracts"."clientId"
          AND contracts.opened < now()
          AND contracts.expires > now() + '1 day'::interval
        ) AS subq
      WHERE subq.status = 'Signed'
      AND subq.id = 12345
```

> ### ?column?
>
> (0 rows)

Comment: The only reason for the 12345 in the one example c.id doesn't exist as it's part of the outer query, I've simply replaced it with a known existing id. If I take the very first example that returned one row and wrap it in select exists() I get false.

Comment: *If I take the very first example that returned one row and wrap it in select exists() I get false* - Can you actually post that `select exists` query? It may seems pointless, but you may have missed some important detail.

Comment: I've made the requested edits. This seems really odd. It's Potgres 9.5.2.

Comment: Maybe it's just a timing thing (you didn't run all the queries the same day...). Your query does depend on `now()` after all. Are you sure that the original query at the top of your question still produces the one row?  Your last query `SELECT 1 FROM ...` would suggest otherwise.

Comment: the contract in question opened 2016-09-01 and expires 2017-08-31 so I'm well within the window. Out of paranoia I checked the clock on the server, it is correct. I re-tested everything again. It's definitely returning 1 row but false on exists, and apparently SELECT 1 returns 0 rows as well. I'm just going to have to re-think my logic.